# On pasting into dojo editor it will allow only plane text

Tags: text, dojo, editor, paste

On pasting into dojo editor it will allow only plane text.
I have DOJO editor , i will copy some content form some page i may contain images and other things along with text.
On pasting in the editor it will take only text.

Comment: Please post your code, so I can provide a specific solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your editor code probably use `SafePaste` plugin, which sanitize clipboard content when pasting in the editor.

More info here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/editor/plugins/SafePaste.html

It is possible to disable it by removing its reference from `data-dojo-props`, example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Editor" id="editor" data-dojo-props="extraPlugins:['safepaste']"></div>
```

By default, it is possible to copy and paste HTML content including links to external images (attached internally to `data-a-dynamic-image`) using `dijit/Editor`, so the limitation it is most probably caused by `SafePaste` plugin.

You can have at look copy and paste (HTML enabled) here: [demo dijit/Editor](http://jaredj.dojotoolkit.org/editor_dojo15/) .